# How to count data on ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In **php** I am sending an `array` back to `ajax` on front end:

```
echo json_encode($totSaved);
```

Then on the front end I do:

```
...
 success: function(data) {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.length);
...
```

Console:

```
console.log(data); = ["128545","128545"]

console.log(data.length); = 19
```

It should be giving me **2**, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `data` seems to be a *string* not an array. The string has 19 characters in it.

Comment: @VLAZ I see, should I do the following then? `var dataLenght = data.split(); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the result is `19` it seems that `data` is a string, not an array. As such you need to parse it, which you can do with `JSON.parse()`:

```
success: function(data) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    var arr = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(arr.length);
  }, /* timeout delay */); 
});
```

If you are always expecting a JSON response you could instead set the `dataType` property in the AJAX request settings to `'json'`. That way jQuery will parse the response for you.

Comment: excellent,t hanks. I was trying var dataLenght = data.split(); but wasn't working, thank you

Comment: had a double check, I use `$.ajax({
                        url: ajax_url,
                        type: 'post',` and didn't specify `dataType`, that's the trick indeed in my case. p.s. thought I had it. Me fault. Thanks.